# Grep in Shell to extract a line from specific string

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, sh

I have a file with below text

> ^[[8mha:AAAAYB+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQSmjNKU4P0+vJLE4u1gvPjexLDVPzxdEuhYV5Rf55ZekOlc7RKnPKH7IxMBQUcQgBdWQnJ9XnJ+TqucMoUEKGSCAEaSwAACsNFCqYAAAAA==^[[0m[ERROR] ^[[8mha:AAAAYB+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQSmjNKU4P0+vJLE4u1gvPjexLDVPzxdEuhYV5Rf55ZekOlc7RKnPKH7IxMBQUcQgBdWQnJ9XnJ+TqucMoUEKGSCAEaSwAACsNFCqYAAAAA==^[[0m[ERROR] /opt/app/ElectronicTransactionVOtoDOMapper.java:[1060,1] error: reached end of file while parsing ^[[8mha:AAAAYB+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQSmjNKU4P0+vJLE4u1gvPjexLDVPzxdEuhYV5Rf55ZekOlc7RKnPKH7IxMBQUcQgBdWQnJ9XnJ+TqucMoUEKGSCAEaSwAACsNFCqYAAAAA==^[[0m[ERROR]
>   -> [Help 1] ^[[8mha:AAAAYB+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQSmjNKU4P0+vJLE4u1gvPjexLDVPzxdEuhYV5Rf55ZekOlc7RKnPKH7IxMBQUcQgBdWQnJ9XnJ+TqucMoUEKGSCAEaSwAACsNFCqYAAAAA==^[[0m[ERROR] ^[[8mha:AAAAYB+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQSmjNKU4P0+vJLE4u1gvPjexLDVPzxdEuhYV5Rf55ZekOlc7RKnPKH7IxMBQUcQgBdWQnJ9XnJ+TqucMoUEKGSCAEaSwAACsNFCqYAAAAA==^[[0m[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch

from the above log, I have to extract only the below:

```
[ERROR]
[ERROR] /opt/app/ElectronicTransactionVOtoDOMapper.java:[1060,1] error: reached end of file while parsing
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch
```

Eventually, I should not get the Junk value in the log instead I need a clear Error message.

Could you please help me in getting the right command in shell?

Comment: Please show your coding efforts.

Comment: I derived this..

cat -v log_10-29-2016_04_12 | grep -o '\[ERROR.*'

but not sure that the command works in all scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

probably should use sed rather than grep here.

```
sed -n '/ERROR/s/.*\(\[ERROR\].*\)$/\1/p' log_10-29-2016_04_12
```

gets only lines containing the word 'ERROR' and strips everything from the left of the '[ERROR]' and prints the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -vRS='^' -F "] " '/ERROR/{print "[ERROR] "$2}' file
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

Try below grep command to achieve the output -

```
vipin@kali:~$ grep "\[ERROR\]" kk.txt |cut -c6-
[ERROR]
[ERROR] /opt/app/ElectronicTransactionVOtoDOMapper.java:[1060,1] error: reached end of file while parsing
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch
```

explanation :
`\[ and \]` for escaping and `-c6-` to print after 6th character till end of line.